# Problem with the code for MSP430F5529 I2C Master communication

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, communication, msp430

First of all, thank you in advance for the attention and the time dispensed understanding my problem.

So, I am developing a system that includes an MSP430F5529 communicating with an AD5933 via I2C. Previously, I did the same thing with an MSP430G2553 everything went smoothly and my code worked perfectly. I did check with an oscilloscope and every data was being sent. I started with that code for my new system and did all the necessary changes, ports, interrupts, registers, from G2553 to F5529.

No matter what, my code stop in verification loops. Especially this one:

```
while (UCB0STAT & UCBBUSY);
```

When I check the bus with an oscilloscope, the SCL is always high and SDA always low. So nothing happened on the bus.

I blink a LED during the code, and that works fine.

My code is bellow, please check it and let me know if you find something wrong, or if you have some idea for me to try out.

```
#include <msp430.h> 

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x0D /**< Address to AD5933. */
#define BAUD_RATE 0x12 /**< Baud Rate value. */
#define SDA_PIN BIT0                                    // msp430F5529 UCB0SDA pin
#define SCL_PIN BIT1                                    // msp430F5529 UCB0SCL pin

signed char byteCtr;
unsigned char *TI_transmit_field;
unsigned char *TI_receive_field;

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;                   // Stop watchdog timer

    //LED configurations
    P1DIR |= BIT1;
    P1OUT |= BIT1;
    P1OUT ^= (BIT1);   //turn on LED

    //MSP configurations to transmit
    P3SEL |= SDA_PIN + SCL_PIN;                 // Assign I2C pins to USCI_B0

    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                        // Enable SW reset
    UCB0CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;       // I2C Master, synchronous mode
    UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCSWRST;              // Use SMCLK, keep SW reset
    UCB0BR0 = BAUD_RATE;                         // set prescaler
    UCB0BR1 = 0;
    UCB0I2CSA = SLAVE_ADDRESS;                  // Set slave address
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                       // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB0IE = UCNACKIE;
    UCB0IE |= UCTXIE;                           // Enable interrupts

    P1OUT ^= (BIT1);                            //turn off LED
    while (UCB0STAT & UCBBUSY)                  //wait for previous traffic to clear
    ;

    //Configuration of the slave registers (SEND DATA)
    unsigned char field[2] = { 0x80, 0xB1 };
    TI_transmit_field = field;
    byteCtr = 2;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;                 // I2C TX, start condition
    while (UCB0STAT & UCBBUSY)
        ;

    while (1)
        ;
}

//INTERRUPTS
#pragma vector = USCI_B0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_B0_ISR(void)
{
    switch (__even_in_range(UCB0IV, 12))
    {
    case 0:
        break;                           // Vector  0: No interrupts
    case 2:
        break;                           // Vector  2: ALIFG
    case 4:
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
        UCB0IFG &= ~UCNACKIFG;
        break;                           // Vector  4: NACKIFG
    case 6:
        break;                           // Vector  6: STTIFG
    case 8:
        break;                           // Vector  8: STPIFG
    case 10:                                  // Vector 10: RXIFG -- I am not using it yet (but I'll)
        if (byteCtr == 0)
        {
            UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
            *TI_receive_field = UCB0RXBUF;
            TI_receive_field++;
        }
        else
        {
            *TI_receive_field = UCB0RXBUF;
            TI_receive_field++;
            byteCtr--;
        }
        break;
    case 12:                                     // Vector 12: TXIFG
        if (byteCtr == 0)
        {
            UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
            UCB0IFG &= ~UCTXIFG;                 // Clear USCI TX int flag
        }
        else
        {
            UCB0TXBUF = *TI_transmit_field;
            TI_transmit_field++;
            byteCtr--;
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick comment: When you're coding the master and you compile and reset during i2c comms, you can hang the line while the slave is waiting for a clock tick. I usually get around this by sending a single CLK pulse during my init function http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/I2C_Tips#External_Slave_Device_Hanging_the_Bus_by_Holding_SDA_Low

Comment: @scld Thank you for your tip. I can I do that? I don't find that information in the link you sent me.

Comment: Note to other readers: To see more context / background, and to avoid duplicating effort, those people interested in this topic may want to read the replies on the TI E2E forum where the OP has asked the same question (["Problem with the code for MSP430F5529 I2C Master communication"](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/596864)) and the related question which is still ongoing (["Problem with I2C communication between MSP430F5529 and AD5933"](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/593848))

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to enable the global interrupts in the initialization. 
Using this line:

```
__enable_interrupt();
```